# Sending the model back to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am sending some values back to my Controller via jQuery like this

```
function update(newValue, updateWhat) {
    $.post("/Dashboard/Update", { Update: updateWhat, Value: newValue });
}
```

When that's posted to the Controller, does the `model` in my View follow? So that I can use my model too in the Controller?

```
@model Dog.Models.Dog
```

Because I need to send the `Id` in my model, but I can use it like this in the .js file

```
var id = @model.DogId
```

Here is my controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Update(int Id, string Update, string Value)
    {
           // Stuff
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "does the model follow" ? The only thing you get in your controller is the values you sent to it.

Comment: Are you trying to send additional data to the controller (i.e. both the model and the the `updateWhat` and `newValue` properties)?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I'd like to send the model as well!

Comment: You need to extract your model from the page. If the model is rendered inside a `<form>` use `form.serialize()`; if not, just get the required values and build a corresponding object. In your controller, set as parameters your model (i.e. an object of your model's type) and the other properties you wish to receive. Modify your jQuery `post` method by adding the model object.

Comment: I don't understand how to make this model object and add it in my post

Comment: Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) out.

Comment: You could create an object model to send back if you do not have a very large model.